# How can the colors of a single window be inverted in OS X?

Tags: macos

How can the colors of a single window be inverted in OS X?

Comment: Please add some description of what you're looking for.  "Inverted" window colors is a bit ambiguous.

Comment: Not what you asked for, but could be useful to someone: To perform this change globally, press `ctrl-opt-cmd-8`.

Answer (score 4):

You can use <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Option ⌥</kbd>+<kbd>Control ⌃</kbd>+<kbd>8</kbd> to invert the video colours of the whole screen.

There's no way to just invert the colours of a single window.

Comment: Hmm. There definitely used to be. In 10.4.

Answer (score 2):

In Mountain Lion, the Ctrl+Opt+Cmd+8 shortcut was deactivated. I first had to activate it for it to work via Keyboard Shortcuts in the System Preferences in the Accessibility tab.

[image: keyboard preferences showing accessilibilty tab]

Answer (score 2):

[Black light](https://michelf.ca/projects/black-light/) software does it, and it does even more.

Comment: Black light works on a screen-by-screen basis, but not by app or window.

Comment: This looks like a good option, as Black Light was most recently updated in December 2023.
(I'm not affiliated with the project)

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>8</kbd> does the whole screen if that helps.

You could make the window full screen!